# Isomorphism between 2 quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M,N$be linear subspaces $L$ then how can we prove that the following map
 $$(M+N)/N\to M/M\cap N$$ defined by $$m+n+N\mapsto m+M\cap N$$ is surjective?
Originally, I need to prove that this map is bijection but I have already proven that this map is injective and well defined,but having hard time to prove surjectivity,please help.

Comment: What does a typical element of $M/(M\cap N)$ look like; i.e., how do you write its general form?  Given such an element, can you find an element of $(M+N)/N$ that is sent there under your map?  Incidentally, note that $n+N=N$, so $m+n+N=m+N$ (assuming here that $n\in N$).

Comment: the typical element is shown above,well your 2nd question is obviously equivalent to the surjectivity of f,i.e what I need!So is there an element that would preimage of arbitrarily taken element of $M/M\cap N$

Comment: Given $x=m+M\cap N$, what element of $(M+N)/N$ might go to $x$?

Comment: $m+n+N$ with n being arbitrary vector in N?

Comment: Yes, which can be written as $m+N$.

Comment: Makes sense, it is too trivial,I thought it shouldnt be.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an arbitrary element $x=m+M\cap N$ of $M/(M\cap N)$, note that $m+N\in (M+N)/N$ is mapped to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $T: M \to (M+N)/N$ by 
          $m \mapsto m+N$. 
Show that it is linear and onto. 
Check the $\ker T$  and is $M\cap N$ 
by the first isomorphism theorem $f:M/(M\cap N) \to (M+N)/N$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).